# How to show the set of remaining items in array when next button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 12 cameras in total, when i select 4 cameras option from a drop down box it show only 4 cameras. Now when i click on the next button i need to display the remaining cameras in the selected layout format. How will it work?

```
<button class="butn" ng-click="previous_view()">Previous</button>
    <button class="butn" id="next_button" ng-click="next_view()">Next</button>
    <label class="head">Layout :</label>
    <select class="layout_lst" ng-model="size" ng-change="setSize()">
        <option ng-repeat="priority in sizeLst" value="{{priority.type}}">{{priority.name}} />
    </select>
    <div layout-wrap flex-wrap>
        <iframe ng-repeat="item in camerasList | limitTo : size" ng-class="size" oncontextmenu="ShowContextMenu()" src={{item.url}} width="337" height="177" allow=loop />
    </div>
</button>
```

//js code

```
 $scope.sizeLst = [
 {
     "name": "2x2",
     "type": "fourscreen"
 }, {
      "name": "3x2",
      "type": "sixscreen"
 }, {
      "name": "4x2",
      "type": "eightscreen"
 }, {
      "name": "3x3",
      "type": "ninescreen"
 }, {
      "name": "3x4",
      "type": "twelvescreen"
 }
 ];

 $scope.camerasList = [
 {
     "name": "camera 1",
     "url": "assets/Nature Beautiful short video 720p HD.mp4",
     "type": "2screen"
  }, {
     "name": "camera 2",
     "url": "assets/videoplayback.mp4",
     "type": "2screen"
   }, {
      "name": "camera 3",
      "url": "assets/Nature Beautiful short video 720p HD.mp4",
      "type": "4screen"
   }, {
      "name": "camera 4",
      "url": "assets/Nature Beautiful short video 720p HD.mp4",
      "type": "4screen"
   }, {
      "name": "camera 5",
      "url": "assets/Nature Beautiful short video 720p HD.mp4",
      "type": "6screen",
   }, {
      "name": "camera 6",
      "url": "assets/Nature Beautiful short video 720p HD.mp4",
      "type": "6screen"
   }, {
      "name": "camera 7",
      "url": "assets/Nature Beautiful short video 720p HD.mp4",
      "type": "8screen"
   }, {
      "name": "camera 8",
      "url": "assets/Nature Beautiful short video 720p HD.mp4",
      "type": "8screen"
   }, {
      "name": "camera 9",
      "url": "assets/Nature Beautiful short video 720p HD.mp4",
      "type": "8screen"
   }, {
      "name": "camera 10",
      "url": "assets/Nature Beautiful short video 720p HD.mp4",
      "type": "8screen"
   }, {
      "name": "camera 11",
      "url": "assets/Nature Beautiful short video 720p HD.mp4",
      "type": "8screen"
   }, {
      "name": "camera 12",
      "url": "assets/Nature Beautiful short video 720p HD.mp4",
      "type": "8screen"
   }


    let videoLst = $scope.camerasList;
    console.log(videoLst);

    $scope.setSize = () => {
        // if ($scope.size == "1x2") {
        //     $scope.camerasList = videoLst.slice(0, 2);
        //     console.log($scope.camerasList)
        // }
        if ($scope.size === "fourscreen") {
            $scope.camerasList = videoLst.slice(0, 4);
            console.log($scope.camerasList)
        }
        if ($scope.size === "sixscreen") {
            $scope.camerasList = videoLst.slice(0, 6);
            console.log($scope.camerasList)
        }
        if ($scope.size === "eightscreen") {
            $scope.camerasList = videoLst.slice(0, 8);
            console.log($scope.camerasList)
        }
        if ($scope.size === "ninescreen") {
            $scope.camerasList = videoLst.slice(0, 9);
            console.log($scope.camerasList)
        }
        if ($scope.size === "twelvescreen") {
            $scope.camerasList = videoLst.slice(0, 12);
            console.log($scope.camerasList)
        }
    }
```

when next button is clicked i need to display the next set of cameras from the array in consider with the layout. Please me with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.slice(start, stop)` in your `next_view()`

When you show the first 4 `.slice(0, 4)` you are getting index 0, 1, 2, 3 ( first 4 items )

If you want to get the next set you will do `.slice(4, 8)` then `.slice(8, 12)`

You can do this using an index.

first time click on `next_view()`

```
 index = 1;
 totalShow = 4;
 start = totalShow * index;
 end = start + totalShow
 .slice(start, end)
```

Then Increase the index by 1 every-time you go to the next set and reset it when changing view.

Here's some more info on slice https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: This works perfect for next button, but how to use this code for previous button?

Comment: Please help me with the previous button.

Comment: Just do the same thing but reduce the index.

Comment: index = index -1;